# Filtering out duplicate entries in collection

Tags: backbone.js

When populating a drop down list with Backbone from a collection, how would I go about not adding duplicate entries, e.g. entries with the same (in this case) organisation name?

Currently what I have is this, which populates a drop down list:

```
[[ _.each(facilities.toJSON(), function(item) { ]]
    <option value="{{ item.ID }}">{{ item.OrganisationName }}</option>
[[ }); ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a helper method on your collection:

```
var Facilities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  getUniqueByProperty: function(propertyName) {
    return _.unique(this.toJSON(), function(item) {
      return item[propertyName];
    });
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
[[ _.each(facilities.getUniqueByProperty('OrganisationName'), function(item) { ]]
  <option value="{{ item.ID }}">{{ item.OrganisationName }}</option>
[[ }); ]]
```

/code sample not tested